# How to pass PIN to access secured printer using PrintService API in java

Tags: java, api

I am using Java Printservice API for one of the requirement in printer task. I am facing some issue while giving a print to secured printer, which requires Username & PIN i.e it fetches automatically the details while giving manual print from system.

Solution is required to fetch the same UserName & Password from system and using java code to pass the same input to printer. Currently unable to pass such properties through PrintService API.

Code:

```
PrintService[] defservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(myFlavor, aset);
boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
printerJob.print();
```